# Linux custom keyboard: set an uppercase space key and autodisable caps lock

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

Wouldn't that be neat? What I want is to make that the upercase of space to be it's scaped secuence: "\ " or "' ' " in order to more easily deal with long filenames under bash and other languages. I could also set a compose for every character to output as it's scaped version.

Also I would want to auto disable caps lock after an specificied time, so I don't have to press it twice every time.
How I could do this in a native way under linux?